# Is there a command in Linux to query a hostname from WINS server

Tags: linux, samba

Someone suggested the command `nmblookup`. But when I ran this command, it issued the following error.

```
$ nmblookup -U 10.140.8.106 -R 'name'
querying name on 10.140.8.106
name_query failed to find name name
```

Which configure file or command line options does `nmblookup` use relating to a query? How does it know the WINS server address?

Thanks

Comment: You have tried to replace the `name` with the hostname you're actually interested in, haven't you?  ([See this example](http://wiki.samba-tng.org/doku.php/pages/manpages/nmblookup.1#examples))

Answer (score 3):

Your command works fine with my WINS server, for any name that actually is in WINS.  I get the failed message that you do, when the name is not in WINS:

```
% nmblookup -U 11.22.33.44 -R 'winchester'
querying winchester on 11.22.33.44
11.22.33.143 winchester<00>

% nmblookup -U 11.22.33.44 -R 'winchesxx'
querying winchesxx on 11.22.33.44
name_query failed to find name winchesxx
```

See the man page for `nmblookup` ("`man nmblookup`") to review the options available.  You provide the address of the WINS server with that `-U` option ("`-U 10.140.8.106`").

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/nmblookup.1.html#contenttoc3), the `-U` option specifies the WINS server to query, and the name to lookup is the first positional argument.